# JavaScript: How to return mapped array from Array.reduce() function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Why does **Code Snippet 1** work while **Code Snippet 2** doesn't?

**Code Snippet 1:**

```
var firstEvents = events.reduce(function(ar, e) {
  var id = e.getId();
  if (e.isRecurringEvent() && e.isAllDayEvent() && !ar.some(function(f) {return f.eventId == id})) {
    ar.push({eventTitle: e.getTitle(), eventId: id, startDate: e.getAllDayStartDate(), endDate: e.getAllDayEndDate()});
  }
  return ar;
}, []);
firstEvents = new Map(firstEvents.map(entry => [entry.eventTitle, entry.startDate]));
```

**Code Snippet 2:**

```
var firstEvents = events.reduce(function(ar, e) {
  var id = e.getId();
  if (e.isRecurringEvent() && e.isAllDayEvent() && !ar.some(function(f) {return f.eventId == id})) {
    ar.push({eventTitle: e.getTitle(), eventId: id, startDate: e.getAllDayStartDate(), endDate: e.getAllDayEndDate()});
  }
  return (new Map(ar.map(entry => [entry.eventTitle, entry.startDate])));
}, []);
```

How would I shorten **Code Snippet 1** correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does Code Snippet 1 work while Code Snippet 2 doesn't?

Because the callback is executed multiple times, and the `new Map` you are returning becomes the `ar` accumulator value in the next call.

> How would I shorten Code Snippet 1 correctly?

To make it a single expression, you would use

```
const firstEvents = new Map(events.reduce(…).map(…));
```

But really the correct solution would be not to use `reduce` and `push` at all, but just `map` and `filter`. To remove duplicate ids, keep track of them in a `Set`, or even better just key another map by them:

```
const firstEventsById = new Map(events.filter(e =>
  e.isRecurringEvent() && e.isAllDayEvent()
).map(e => {
  var id = e.getId();
  return [id, {
    eventTitle: e.getTitle(),
    // eventId: id,
    startDate: e.getAllDayStartDate(),
    // endDate: e.getAllDayEndDate()
  }];
}).reverse());
const startDatesByTitle = new Map(Array.from(firstEventsById.values(), entry =>
  [entry.eventTitle, entry.startDate]
));
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you give me a live example using `map` and `filter`?

Comment: Thank you very much!